# Depth of field of the human eye

Tags: optics, biophysics, lenses, vision

When reading about the basics of photography and the physics involved, I learned about  *depth of field*. Long story short, the message is that with a smaller aperture, the length of the depth of field increases. For a wide-open aperture one gets a smooth bokeh for example.

The human eye does have an aperture as well (the iris). But I never noticed seeing any different with respect to depth of field no matter if it was a darker (wider iris) or brighter (narrow iris) environment.

Why is this difference presumably not as pronounced as it is for photography? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: The same principle applies to eyes. That's a major reason why squinting can help you see more clearly. See http://www.invision2020.com/see-better-squint/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your eyes are young, you will not experience a difference.

However, once you age, depth of field makes a BIG difference, because your eye gradually loses the ability to shift the focus of the lens. To see close objects sharply then requires bright illumination so your iris contracts to a small opening and your depth of focus goes up; this compensates for the loss of ability to focus on close objects.

Answer (score 1):

With increasing age *power of accomodation* to vary iris diameter diminishes. So to compensate for focussing inability (contraction of tiny sphincter like muscles in the iris that work like the diaphragm in a camera) brighter objects are used/needed by the old. You seem to be young with no such problem.